# Displaying Default Value of "N/A" When Date Time Field is Null

Tags: sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint column that is supposed to capture date and time values.
How can I display a value of "N/A" when the field is null (is blank) and also display the actual value if one was entered?

Comment: are you able to access code or are you just doing everything through the GUI?

Comment: it could be as simple as `!(mydate == null) ? mydate : "n/a"` if you have code access.

Comment: I would have to do this in a formula field in the Sharepoint column but the wrinkle is to be able to display the actual date time value when there and display the "N/A" literal when there are null values

Comment: I am thinking that I would need to create a separate display column that I could use in the view that would handle the logic to show actual date/times value or the literal "N/A"

Answer (score 2):

Put a calculated value in the default value for the column?  This will of course depend on when the Date is supposed to get populated.

=IF(ISBLANK[myDate],"N/A","[myDate])

Add a new column that is based on the Date column that is actually a calculated column referencing the Date column utilizing the same calculation.

Comment: I am getting the following Sharepoint error:
The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported

Comment: I tried the following formula and still is getting syntax error message in Sharepoint 2007
=IF(ISBLANK[myDate],"N/A","[myDate])

Comment: The foemula is missing a " character at the end.

`=IF(ISBLANK[myDate],"N/A","[myDate]")`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. instead of a comma (,) you have to use a different operator depending the Region/Local settings of your site.
E.g. for German local I had to use a semi-column (;) in my formula
Very disappointing behaviour!

Comment: yep but remember that the actual function names also changes. Find a (not complete) reference here http://wwwhome.ewi.utwente.nl/~trieschn/excel/excel.html

Answer (score 0):

I have used 2 calculated columns:

```
Cal-1 =>  =TEXT([Expiration Date],"yyyy") ---> if blank -it shows 1899
Cal-2=>   =IF([Cal-1]="1899","N/A",[Cal-1])     ----> then it shows N/A for place where it is null
```